# How to write dates to csv file in R?

Tags: r, csv, quantmod

I'm trying to get dividend information from the web and save it to a .csv file. My code is:

```
library(quantmod)
stokname = 'XOM'
divseries = getDividends(stokname)
write.csv(divseries, file = paste("C:/DATA/dividends/",stokname,".csv", sep = ""), row.names=FALSE)
```

this works, but when I save it, all I have is the dividends, without the dates. How can I write the dates to the file?

Comment: Try `?write.zoo` instead.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich post it, could be useful for future readers

Comment: @DavidArenburg: but that's so much more work than a 3-word comment! ;-)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich and now someone shamelessly stole it. Not sure if to downvote or upvote now <sigh>

Comment: @DavidArenburg: And Dirk closed it as a duplicate, so I'm too late! :)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich  At least you can always blame me.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: That's a given.